# Two counts from different Columns

Tags: r

I have a full outer join data table in R that contains the information about the contracts of two months.

I have 3 possibilities:

- The contracts that I have in both months
- Finished contracts that I have in the last month, but not in the current month
- New Contracts that I have just in the current month

I need group the contracts and make two counts, one count of contracts for each month.

```
 #   Month.x  Contract.x Stage.x Month.y Contract.y Stage.y
 # 1 201612   1000       Stage1  201701  1000       Stage 2
 # 2 201612   1001       Stage1  201701  1001       Stage 1
 # 3 201612   1002       Stage1  NA      NA         NA
 # 4 NA       NA         NA      201701  1003       Stage 1
 # 5 201612   1004       Stage1  201701  1004       Stage 2
 # 6 201612   1005       Stage1  201701  1005       Stage 1
 # 7 201612   1006       Stage1  NA      NA         NA
 # 8 NA       NA         NA      201701  1007       Stage 1
```

I need to have something like this:

```
 #   Month.x  Num_contract.x Stage.x Month.y Num_Contract.y Stage.y
 # 1 201612   2              Stage1  201701  2              Stage 2
 # 2 201612   2              Stage1  201701  2              Stage 1
 # 3 201612   2              Stage1  NA      0              NA
 # 4 NA       0              NA      201701  2              Stage 1
```

I just did the count of one column and I got this result

```
 #    Month.x Num_contracts  Stage.x Month.y  Stage.y
 # 1 201612   2              Stage1  201701   Stage 2
 # 2 201612   2              Stage1  201701   Stage 1
 # 3 201612   2              Stage1  NA       NA
 # 4 NA       2              NA      201701   Stage 1
```

How can I include more counts in the code, each one using different variables?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please first show us what you tried as @Jaap said. Anyways, IMO doing the grouping after the joins is a bad idea plus it is unclear how you join the tables. A better approach would be to group by, count and then use `tidyr::spread()`

Comment: I did the count with `table[, .(Num_Contracts=.N), by = list(Month.x,Stage.x,Month.y,Stage.y)]`I need to know how can I do 2 counts on this table. I want one with the numbers of the contract.x and other with the contract.y. I did this in SAS and it was easy because I simply used Count(contract.x), count(contract.y) and grouped by the same variables. Sorry for some mistake, I'm new in R.